# why operational database are not fulfilling business challenges as data warehouse?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

i have a question why operational database are not fulfilling business challenges as data warehouse?
in operational database i can create reports in details about any product or any thing and i can issue statistical reports with charts and diagrams, so why the operational database can not use as data warehouse?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually an operational database only keeps track of the current state of each record.

The purpose of a data warehouse is two-fold:
- Keep track of historic events without overwhelming the operational database;
- Isolate OLAP queries so that they don't impact the load on the operational datastore.

If you try to query your operational data store for sales per product line per month for the past year the amount of joins required, as well as the amount of information you need to read from storage may cause performance degradation on your operational database.

A data warehouse tries to avoid this by 1) keeping things separated and 2) denormalising the data model (Kimball approach) so that query plans are simpler.

I suggest reading The Data Warehouse Toolkit, by Ralph Kimball. The first chapter deals precisely with this question: why do we need a data warehouse if we already have an operational data store?

Answer (score 0):

> i can create reports in details about any product or any thing
>
> and i can issue statistical reports with charts and diagrams

Yes you can but a business user can not as they don't know SQL. And you it's very difficult to put a BI tool (for a business users to use) over the top of an operational database for many reasons:

- The data model is not built for an end user to understand. A data warehouse data model *is* (i.e. there is ONE table for customers that has everything about a customer in it rather than being split into addresses, accounts etc.)
- The operational data store is probably missing important reporting reference data such as grouping levels and hierarchies
- A slowly changing dimension is a method of 'transparently' modelling changes to for example, customers. An operational data model generally doesn't do this very well. You need to understand all the table and join them correctly, if this information is even stored

There are many other reasons but these just serve to address your points

When you get to the point that you are too busy to service business users requests, and you are issuing reports that don't match from one day to the other, you'll start to see the value of a data warehouse.